# Why does the data parameter of pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame need to be nested?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, types

I am trying to create a simple DataFrame from a list and want to understand the logic.

My first attempt from the documentation was

```
import pyspark
sc: pyspark.SparkContext = pyspark.SparkContext(master='local[*]', appName='TestApp')
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([1, 2], schema=['a', 'b'])
```

This raises `TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'int'>.`

From looking at an example I changed my last line to

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2]], schema=['a', 'b'])
```

which gives me the expected result:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+

None
```

Can someone explain to me why I have to nest the data parameter?

(Less relevant side question: Where does the `None` in the output come from?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's how the Spark API works. Each item in the list should represent a row, in the form of a list/tuple/dict. If you gave a list `[1, 2]`, then you're saying that row 1 is 1 and row 2 is 2, which does not make sense. You want row 1 to be `[1, 2]`, so putting the rows in a list gives `[[1, 2]]`.

You probably used `print(df.show())`. `df.show()` on its own will print out the dataframe, and returns `None`, so you're calling `print(None)`. That's why you're seeing `None`. Just doing `df.show()` is enough.